# can't query EXEC command with pyodbc python module

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm using pyodbc to querying MSQLS databases, every works fine until I try to use EXECUTE command

Example

```
querys= """
    EXEC sys.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0', N'ProcessorNameString';
    """
```

I get

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.
```

Also I try with ODBC way

```
query= r'{call sys.xp_instance_regread ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE", "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\pvscsi\Parameters\Device", "DriverParameter")}'
```

and I get

```
pyodbc.DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Any idea to solve this issue?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments to the stored procedure contain backslashes so you must either double them up in a regular string literal ...

```py
" ... N'HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\CentralProcessor\\0', ... "
```

... or use a "raw string"

```py
r" ... N'HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0', ... "
```

Comment: My God, I feel, really newbie. Thanks Gord